# MySQL forward engineer cannot add foreign key error 1215

Tags: key, mysql-workbench

So I believe I designed the table and the relationships perfectly. But somehow every time when I use the forward engineer to create script I keep getting the 1215 cannot add foreign key error.
   Totally I got three foreign key in two different tables but only this table "Sales" get errors. It has a foreign key "restaurantnumber" referenced thetable "restaurant".
  Codes are below and can anyone shed some light on it?

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Restaurant`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Restaurant` (
  `RestaurantNumber` CHAR(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Restaurant ID, primary key,same as the mydb,nothing needs to be changed',
  `RestaurantAddress` VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'same as the mydb,nothing needs to be changed',
  `FranchiseeNumber` CHAR(2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key reference to fanchisee table',
  `ContractType` CHAR(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign key referenced to table contract',
  PRIMARY KEY (`RestaurantNumber`),
  INDEX `franchiseenumber_idx` (`FranchiseeNumber` ASC),
  INDEX `contracttype_idx` (`ContractType` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `franchiseenumber`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FranchiseeNumber`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Franchisee` (`FranchiseeNumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `contracttype`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ContractType`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Contract` (`ContractType`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;



-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Sales`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Sales` (
`SalesNumber` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID of the each sales\' record,primary key.',
  `SalesMonthly` INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'that is the monthly sales volume for each restaurant,primry key',
  `RestaurantNumber` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SalesNumber`, `SalesMonthly`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `SalesNumber_UNIQUE` (`SalesNumber` ASC),
  INDEX `restaurantnumber_idx` (`RestaurantNumber` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `RestaurantNumber`
    FOREIGN KEY (`RestaurantNumber`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Restaurant` (`RestaurantNumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed
>   Fetching back view definitions in final form.
>   Nothing to fetch

Comment: Which one failed? Can you give us any more info, like an error message?

Comment: the sales table, it has a foreign key "restaurantnumber" referenced to table restaurant.

Comment: i have the same problem, when i checked the generated script I found out that the referenced table creation statement positioned after the referencing table. I'm not sure what caused workbench to set it in that order but you may have the same problem.